# How to CAST a value in PostgreSQL for use in WHERE with LIKE statement?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, casting

I'm trying to fix a SQL query for later convert it to Doctrine2 DQL since it's part of a Symfony2 project. This is what my DDL has:

```
CREATE TABLE "nomencladores"."norma" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "comite_tecnico_id" int4,
    "numero" VARCHAR (10) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
    "anno" int4 NOT NULL,
    "nombre" VARCHAR (255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
    "activo" bool,
    CONSTRAINT "norma_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_f00cbe8e84edad75" FOREIGN KEY ("comite_tecnico_id") REFERENCES "nomencladores"."comite_tecnico" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) WITH (OIDS = FALSE);
```

And I'm trying to execute a LIKE query to find `%45%` and I've tried all this queries without success:

**The one generated by Doctrine2 in DQL**

```
SELECT
    n0_.numero AS numero0,
    n0_.anno AS anno1,
    n0_. ID AS id2,
    n0_.nombre AS nombre3,
    n0_.activo AS activo4,
    n0_.comite_tecnico_id AS comite_tecnico_id5
FROM
    nomencladores.norma n0_
WHERE
    n0_.anno LIKE %45%;
```

**Trying to cast the values**

```
SELECT
    n0_.numero AS numero0,
    n0_.anno AS anno1,
    n0_. ID AS id2,
    n0_.nombre AS nombre3,
    n0_.activo AS activo4,
    n0_.comite_tecnico_id AS comite_tecnico_id5
FROM
    nomencladores.norma n0_
WHERE
    CAST (n0_.anno AS CHAR) LIKE %45%;
```

---

```
SELECT
    n0_.numero AS numero0,
    n0_.anno AS anno1,
    n0_. ID AS id2,
    n0_.nombre AS nombre3,
    n0_.activo AS activo4,
    n0_.comite_tecnico_id AS comite_tecnico_id5
FROM
    nomencladores.norma n0_
WHERE
    CAST (n0_.anno, "FM9999") LIKE %45%
```

---

```
SELECT
    n0_.numero AS numero0,
    n0_.anno AS anno1,
    n0_. ID AS id2,
    n0_.nombre AS nombre3,
    n0_.activo AS activo4,
    n0_.comite_tecnico_id AS comite_tecnico_id5
FROM
    nomencladores.norma n0_
WHERE
    to_char(n0_.anno, "FM9999") LIKE %45%
```

---

```
SELECT
    n0_.numero AS numero0,
    n0_.anno AS anno1,
    n0_. ID AS id2,
    n0_.nombre AS nombre3,
    n0_.activo AS activo4,
    n0_.comite_tecnico_id AS comite_tecnico_id5
FROM
    nomencladores.norma n0_
WHERE
    n0_.anno::text LIKE "%45%"
```

And none works, what is the right way to achieve this on PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax could be:

```
WHERE n0_.anno::text LIKE '%45%';
```

You need to [cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) the number to `text` (or `varchar`) before you can use it with the [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) operator.
The right hand argument for `LIKE` is a `text` value. Your input is a *string literal* to be precise. You need [single quotes for values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS), double quotes are for identifiers.

**If** `anno` is supposed to hold a year and you are just interested in the *last two digits*, make that:

```
WHERE n0_.anno::text LIKE '%45';
```

Or better, yet:

```
WHERE n0_.anno % 100 = 45;
```

`%` being the [modulo operator.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) (Not related to the `%` symbol in `LIKE` patterns!)
`45` (without quotes) being a [*numeric constant*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC).